# Closing and Reopening your own questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closing

Not sure if this belongs here or meta.SO but should the Original Poster be allowed to vote to close or reopen his/her own posts?  Or is it just because of the private beta?

Comment: We can always vote to close our own questions with enough rep, I think we get a reopen vote too. You can vote to close your own questions earlier than other questions

Comment: @Rarity And does it make sense given potential bias?

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to abuse the system to close your own question, and you only get one reopen vote. It's a good way to let people know you think the question is worthy of being opened again, but it requires 4 others to agree, just like any other question.

Comment: @Rarity Point taken but where there is 4 there might as well be 5 wouldn't you agree?  Besides I don't know if anyone except Mods even know that who cast the votes.

Comment: It appears this is [officially by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/why-can-you-vote-to-reopen-your-own-question) and has been for quite a while. It also appears SE won't let me post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rarity said in the comments, [this is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/why-can-you-vote-to-reopen-your-own-question). The reputation requirement is different during private and public betas, but the principle is the same.

Since four other people (or a moderator) need to agree with the vote, there's little chance for abuse.

Comment: To respond to the "where there is 4 there might as well be 5" I would add that 1 reopen vote is very different than 0.